# do_action pass array argument as reference not copy

Tags: actions

I have successive hooks to an action which are passed an associative array like: `do_action($array)`

I am trying to update the values in this array in the multiple `add_action` calls, however each add_action is getting a copy of the passed array, not a reference.

How do I pass a reference? I am using PHP 5.

Answer (score 5):

The way to pass by reference to a WP action is with:
`do_action_ref_array('action_hook', array(&$data) );`

Answer (score 4):

`do_action` which is hooked using `add_action` is not meant for altering values more then its meant for executing your function at a certain point.  Instead use 
`apply_filter` which is hooked using `add_filter` which is meant to allow altering a value.

Comment: Thanks Bainternet, I'm working with a plugin so it's not possible to change `add_action` to `add_filter` without editing their core.

Comment: In that case declare a global and modify its value instead of whats past to your hooked functions.

Comment: Haha why didn't I think of that? I'm always looking for a more complicated way to do things! :-/

Comment: MUCH simpler! Thanks, I would never thought of that (no idea why... but I just wouldn't...)